# jquery - unwanted propagation effect

Tags: jquery, listener, event-propagation

I have a live listener on a class which adds some content.
This is somehow calling this listener repeatedly.  How can I turn off propagatio in this case?

```
SomeContent = "<p>Some content<p>";
moreContent  = "<p>More content<p>";

$('.myClass').live('change', function (event){                  
    var thisOption = $(this);                               

    // event.preventDefault(); - does not work              
    // event.stopImmediatePropagation(); - does not work

    var MyLocation = thisOption.closest('tr').next('tr');               
    // $(MyLocation).html("");                  
    var thisTplReasons = $(moreContent);
    thisTplReasons.appendTo(MyLocation).page();

    return false;
});
```

Comment: It's a jquery mobile think to dynamically add their css on the fly. I removed it, but no difference

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery live function has some flaws documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/). The interesting part of the list is this statement

> Calling event.stopPropagation() in the event handler is ineffective in stopping event handlers attached lower in the document; the event has already propagated to document.

You should use the new jQuery mechanism "on" (see [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) instead of "live" and a call to event.stopPropagation() should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Events are first captured until it reaches the target element, and then bubbled up. During the event flow, an event can be responded to at any element in the path (an observer) in either phase by causing an action, and/or by stopping the event (with method event.stopPropagation() for W3C-conforming browsers and command event.cancelBubble = true for Internet Explorer), and/or by cancelling the default action for the event.

[*Source wiki*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Event_flow)

Also,

jQuery *[says](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)*

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

Description: Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Hope this helps.